# How do I store all values of a variable in AnyLogic?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am using discrete event simulation methodology in my project. I have a variable in my simulation called RuleBreak which can be either 0 or 1 which is evaluated for each Agent upon entering the Sink block. I am trying to store every value of the RuleBreak variable in a data frame. I have already tried using the Data Set element in the Analytics palette. However, this only allows you to obtain the value of the variable at a specific recurring time. I need the value of RuleBreak only when an agent enters the Sink block. Can anyone help me with this?

Below is an image of the Sink block, where I set the value of RuleBreak to be either 0 or 1.

[image]

Then here is an image of the Data Set element that I use from the Analytics palette. Notice, that I can only collect the value of RuleBreak at a specific recurring time and cannot obtain the values for all Agents that enter the Sink block.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give any code examples of things you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your dataset element use "Do not update data automatically" and at the end of your "on enter" action of your sink do:

```
dataset.update();
```

And that's it :)